# How do Biblical Unitarians interpret Isaiah 9:6?

Tags: exegesis, christology, isaiah, unitarianism

Unlike Jehovah's Witnesses, BUs don't have a conception of lesser "gods". Given this, how do they interpret Isaiah 9:6, which calls Jesus the following titles:

> For a child will be born for us,
> a son will be given to us,
> and the government will be on his shoulders.
> He will be named
> Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God,
> Eternal Father, Prince of Peace. (CSB)

Note the use of "Mighty God", identifying Jesus as divine.

Comment: BUs don't have a conception of lesser gods. This is untrue. They recognise all manner of gods including the 'god of this world'. For a comprehensive answer revisedenglishversion.com/Isaiah/chapter9/6 – 
steveowen
 23 secs ago

Comment: @steveowen interesting - wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link Steve Owen gives, [Isaiah 9:6 Commentary](https://www.revisedenglishversion.com/Isaiah/chapter9/6), REV translation,

> "“**Mighty Hero**.” The phrase is usually translated as “Mighty God” in
> most English Bibles. **Actually, “mighty god” would not be a bad
> translation if people realized that in the Hebrew language the word
> “god/God” (Elohim; also El) had a much wider range of application than
> it does in English**. People familiar with the Semitic languages know
> that **a man who is acting with God’s authority can be called “god.”**
> Although English makes a clear distinction between “God” and “god,”
> the Hebrew language, which has only capital letters, cannot. Hebrew
> only would have **GOD, no matter if it referred to the Father or a
> person acting with divine authority**. Thus, a better translation of
> Isaiah 9:6 for the English reader would be “mighty hero,” or “divine
> hero.” **Both Martin Luther and James Moffatt translated the phrase as
> “divine hero” in their Bibles**. (For more on the flexible use of “God,”
> see the commentary on Heb. 1:8). For an alternative explanation of the
> name, see below under “Father of the Coming Age.”
>
> The phrase in Isaiah 9:6 that most English versions translate as
> “Mighty God” is el gibbor in the Hebrew. That very phrase, in the
> plural form, **is used in Ezekiel 32:21 of “heroes” and mighty men. The
> NIV translates the phrase in Ezekiel as “mighty leaders,” and the KJV
> and NASB translate it as “the strong among the mighty.”** The Hebrew
> phrase, when used in the singular, can refer to one “mighty leader”
> just as when used in the plural it can refer to many “mighty leaders.”
>
> **There is no justification in the context of Isaiah 9 for believing
> that this verse refers to the Messiah as part of the Trinity. It
> refers to God’s appointed ruler**. The opening verse of the chapter
> foretells a time when “there will be no more gloom for those who were
> in anguish.” All war and death will cease, and “every boot of the
> tramping warrior…and the garments rolled in blood…will be fuel for the
> fire” (Isa. 9:5). How will this come to pass? The chapter goes on:
> “for to us a child is born” (Isa. 9:6). There is no hint that this
> child will be “God,” and reputable Trinitarian scholars will assert
> that the Jews of the Old Testament knew nothing of an “incarnation.”
> **For them, the Messiah was going to be a man anointed by God**. He would
> start as a child, which of course Yahweh, their eternal God, could
> never be. And what a great ruler this man would grow to be: “the
> government will be on his shoulders. And he will be called Wonderful
> Counselor, Mighty Hero, Father of the Coming Age, Prince of Peace.”
> Furthermore, “he will reign on David’s throne (Isa. 9:7), which could
> never be said of God. God could never sit on David’s throne. But God’s
> Messiah, “the Son of David,” could (cp. Matt. 9:27). **Thus, a study of
> the verse in its context reveals that it does not refer to the Trinity
> at all, but to the Messiah, the son of David and the Son of God.**"

I would add that the phrase is 'mighty god', not 'Almighty God'. Very different. Also, remember the 'gods' that Jesus refers to in John 10:34 - same idea. Just as Psalm 82:6 doesn't mean we have to expand God to multiple persons, according to BUs Isaiah 9:6 is much more straightforwardly explained as referring to a heroic man who is anointed by God.

Answer (score 0):

One explanation Unitarians use: "*will be named* is not *is*. People just will name him Mighty God, but this doesn't mean he *is* Mighty God".

But I believe that "will be named" is a Jewish turn of speech meaning "widely known as", or "recognized as", including "being". Examples:

> And a highway will be there; it *will be called* the Way of Holiness (Is. 35:8)

> For your Maker is your husband—
> the Lord Almighty *is* his name—
> the Holy One of Israel is your Redeemer;
> he *is called* the God of all the earth. (Is. 54:5, synonymical rhyme, "is" here is the synonym of "is called")

> for my house *will be called* a house of prayer for all nations (Is. 56:7)

> He will be great and *will be called* the Son of the Most High (Luke 1:32. He actually *is* the Son of Most High)

> And you, my child, *will be called* a prophet of the Most High (Luke 1:76. John the Baptist actually *is* the prophet)

It's just the turn of speech meaning "is, and widely known as"